# jQuery document.ready not called during rails integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara-webkit

I have an integration test that fails for a page that depends heavily on javacript. The same page runs just fine from the browser.
Simplifying the test to a bare minimum I found out that just testing for the presence of a selector that is added by javascript after the page load, would fail.

After precompiling the test assets and using save_and_open_page I found that the handler for the jQuery ready event is **not running** during the integration test.

I didn't find any references to this problem, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.
Can anyone help me figuring this out?

I'm using using rails 3.2.11, RSpec 2.13.0, Capybara 2.0.3 and capybara-webkit 0.14.2

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am getting bit pretty much the exact same thing.

Comment: If the JavaScript that you are waiting for are JQuery AJAX requests, Thoughtbot's post on waiting for ajax may help: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails uses webdriver which doesn't handle JS. If you want JS support you'd need to use one of the JS-aware drivers, like Selenium (which runs full featured browser), capybara-webkit or poltergeist (which are headless webkit browsers). There are many others but these three are most popular.

Comment: I am aware of it. You didn't notice it but I am using capybara-webkit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for me by examining my AJAX request. The problem was that I was requesting a 'http://..." instead of '/' of my page. This meant that it raised a CORS ('ajax request from outside the domain') even though the request looked like it was coming from inside the domain.

My original symptom was 'javascript-inserted HTML elements are not on the page when testing using Capybara with Poltergeist or Selenium (but are on the page when running the application).'